# Grab & encapsulate text using BASH Script

Tags: linux, bash

I am making a script, using bash, that grabs text from iwconfig & stores them in variables.  Here is what I have so far:

```
 DEVICE_ESSID=iwconfig wlan0 | grep -e "ESSID:" | awk '{print $2}'
 DEVICE_IEEE=iwconfig wlan0 | grep -e "ESSID" | awk '{$3}'
 DEVICE_SIGNAL= ``
 DEVICE_FREQ=``
 DEVICE_MAC=``
 timestamp=$(date +%s%N)
```

I need to grab:

```
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: A4:2B:B0:EB:8D:E2
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To capture the output of a command in a variable you can use

```
DEVICE_ESSID=$(iwconfig wlan0 | grep -e "ESSID:" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Note the `$(...)` syntax which captures the output of a command.

Now let us assume you have `iwconfig wlan0` output like this:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"my-ssid"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 25:D3:57:A8:F4:35   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:21  Invalid misc:12203   Missed beacon:0
```

The parsing can get a bit ugly and there are many ways to do it. `awk` is helpful and powerful if you know what you do (I don't). I'm also not sure how stable the output of `iwconfig` is and how recommended this approach should be.

```
DEVICE_ESSID=$(iwconfig wlan0 | awk '/ESSID:/ { print $4 }' | sed 's/ESSID:"\(.*\)"/\1/')
DEVICE_IEEE=$(iwconfig wlan0 | awk '/ESSID:/ { print $3 }')
DEVICE_SIGNAL=$(iwconfig wlan0 | awk '/Signal level/ { print $4 }' | awk -F= '{print $2}')
DEVICE_FREQ=$(iwconfig wlan0 | awk '/Frequency/ { print $2 }' | awk -F: '{print $2}')
DEVICE_MAC=$(iwconfig wlan0 | awk '/Access Point/ { print $6 }')
```